# ag-grid angular - Grid width should adjust to content

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row pt-3">

    <!-- Linke Hälfte: Filter -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>Filters</h2>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- main-content -->
    <div class="col-lg-8 align-items-center">
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="width: 100%"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
        [pagination]="true"
        [paginationAutoPageSize]="true"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        (firstDataRendered)="autoSizeAll(true)"
        domLayout="autoHeight"
      >
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </div> <!-- main-content ende -->
  </div>
</div>
```

In the .ts file:

```
  autoSizeAll(skipHeader: boolean) {
    const allColumnIds: string[] = [];
    this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns()!.forEach((column) => {
      allColumnIds.push(column.getId());
    });
    this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, skipHeader);
  }
```

So the columns width fits their content. That is perfect.
But the whole ag-grid is too wide:

[image]

See the orange box in the screenshot.

When i remove **style="width: 100%"** from the ag-grid, the whole ag-grid is too thin.

Is there a way to tell ag-grid "use as much with of the parent as needed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by myself:

Html:

```
<div [ngStyle]="style" class="col-lg-8 align-items-center content-height max-content-width pe-0">
      <ag-grid-angular
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        (firstDataRendered)="changeGrid()"
      >
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

.ts:

```
public style: any = {
    'max-width': '1680px',
  };

changeGrid() {
    this.autoSizeAll(true);

    if (this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() < 26) {
      this.gridApi.setDomLayout('autoHeight');
    } else {
      this.gridApi.setDomLayout('normal');
    }

    var width = 15;
    this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns()!.forEach((column) => {
      width += column.getActualWidth();
    });
    this.style = {
      'max-width': width + 'px'
    }
  }

  autoSizeAll(skipHeader: boolean) {
    const allColumnIds: string[] = [];
    this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns()!.forEach((column) => {
      allColumnIds.push(column.getId());
    });
    this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, skipHeader);
  }
```